# Prisma : how can I find all elements that match an id list?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am using Prisma with NextJs.

In my API, I send to the back end a list of numbers that correspond to id's of objects in my database.

As an example, if I receive the list `[1, 2, 12]`, I would like to return the objects where the id is either 1, 2 or 12

This is part of a query that is more complex ( sorting / counting / ... ) but I am blocking at the first step with is to get the list of elements

So far I have this :

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()


export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Only POST requests allowed for this route' })
    } else {
        const { signes_id } = req.query
        const signes_array = signes_id.split(",").map(function(item) {
            return parseInt(item)
        })
        console.log(signes_array)
        const ret = await prisma.signe.findMany({
            where: {
                id: Number(signes_array),
            }
        })
        res.status(200).send(ret)
    }
}
```

This does not work as `Number` expects an int, not an array of int

How can I write the query such as it returns the needed array of objects ?
And how can I deal with id's that do not match ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to query by multiple `id` inside `findMany`.

Example:

```js
 const ret = await prisma.signe.findMany({
            where: {
                id: { in: [1, 2, 12] },
            }
        })
```

More details are available in the [prisma client reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in).

Comment: This will filter duplicate posts and bring them back. What if you want to bring them all?

Comment: @nounlace just to clarify, are you asking what to do if you want duplicate records to be returned by `findMany` when you have an array of `id` fields with duplicate `id` values?

Comment: yup yup exactly

Comment: @nounlace Hey, sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do that with a single Prisma query at the moment. I would suggest fetching the entries _without_ duplicates and then organizing them _with_ duplicates inside your application code. If you make a separate question for this and link it, I'd be happy to provide a code snippet that shows how to accomplish this.